# Reset Django Form

Tags: python, mysql, django

I would like to know How it's possible to clear (Reset) a Form when you are completing it ?

I can submit the Form to my MySQL Database and I thought that Reset process was the same, but apparently no. I just wan to add I'm really stuck with Django, I'm learning lots of tutorial per days too.

```
<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html>

<body>

<h1 align="center"> Formulaire d'acte de naissance </h1>

<form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}

<h3> Partie contenant les informations de l'enfant</h3>
{{ Cform.as_ul}} <!-- Display child part formulary -->
{{ value|date:"%d/%m/%Y" }}
{{ value|time:"H:M" }}

<h3> Partie contenant les informations des parents </h3>
{{ Pform.as_ul }} <!-- Display parent part formulary -->
{{ value|date:"%d/%m/%Y" }}

<br></br>

<input type ="submit" value="Valider le formulaire" />
<input type ="reset" value="Reset" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my views.py file :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Child, Parent
from .forms import ChildForm, ParentForm

# Create your views here.

def BirthCertificateAccueil(request) :
    # Fonction permettant de créer la page d'accueil de la rubrique Acte de Naissance 

    #Cherche le fichier html accueil et le renvois
    template = loader.get_template('accueil.html') 
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))

def Formulary(request) :
    # Fonction permettant de créer le formulaire Acte de Naissance et le remplissage

        Cform = ChildForm(request.POST or None) 
        Pform = ParentForm(request.POST or None)

        if Cform.is_valid() and Pform.is_valid() :   # Vérification sur la validité des données
            Cform.save()
            Pform.save()

        context = {
            "Cform" : Cform,
            "Pform" : Pform,
           }

        return render(request, 'birthform.html', context)
```

This is my urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accueil$', views.BirthCertificateAccueil),
    url(r'^formulaire$', views.Formulary),
]
```

It's a completely false method or I missed something ?

Thank you ;)

PS : There is a part on Stack where I can improve my project/scripts with developers ? Because I'm alone to make this project, and as beginner, it's very hard :/

[image: My localhost BirthCertificate page]

Comment: Do you mean rendering an empty form after creation?

Comment: During the creation, I would like to reset all fields instead of clean manually each one.

Comment: what's the view that you call to display your form? can you show your urls?

Comment: @ettanany I edited my post with the urls.py file

Comment: It's BEFORE a submit ! Clear all fields before to submit in order to begin a new one. Not a duplicate because all answers are for after submission ..

Comment: I think what you might want is a redirect after successful save. What you can do is do a `return HttpResponseRedirect('/formulaire')` after your save operations inside the if conditions.
Or, you if you don't want to redirect, you have to define the context in the if condition and render html from there. Like `context = {"Cform": ChildForm(), "Pform": ParentForm()}; return render(request, 'birthform.html', context)`. I can submit this as an answer if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I know this is long gone, but where you able to figure this out? I also want to just use the standard html `<input type="reset" />` functionality with Django.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is passing the form to context with post values that you get once.You just need to call the form before context. This way every time it will show you empty form after saving the result.

```
 if Cform.is_valid() and Pform.is_valid() :   
     Cform.save()
     Pform.save()
 Cform = ChildForm() 
 Pform = ParentForm()   
 context = {
        "Cform" : Cform,
        "Pform" : Pform,
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is customary to use [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for form submissions. What you are missing is a redirect after the successful validation of the submitted form values:

```py
if Cform.is_valid() and Pform.is_valid() :
    Cform.save()
    Pform.save()
    return redirect('/formulaire')  # <- This.
```